# Speeding up indexing in large-dimensional matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing

I'm trying to simulate a large-dimensional Markov chain in Matlab. The transition matrix is approx [6000,6000].

I have vectorized the code as much as I can, but it is still very slow (approx 4 seconds). The culprit is the indexing of the large matrix - 65% of the time is spent on line 37 (`t2 = cum_transition(value(t-1,:),:);`).

Is there anything I can do to speed this up? The actual problem has dimensions that are even larger and will need be called very many times during optimization of a larger function.

```
clear
clc

% dimension of transition matrix
dim = 6000;

% goal: simulate n_year periods, for n_ppl individuals
n_ppl = 1000;
n_year = 100;

% transition matrix: prob_ij = prob_j given i. \sum_j prob_ij = 1
transition = rand(dim);
transition = transition./repmat(sum(transition,2),1,dim); %so that probabiltiies sum to 1
cum_transition = cumsum(transition,2); % cumulative (along the row) probabitliy

% generate random numbers to use as simulate the chain
rand_numbers = rand(n_year, n_ppl);

% value = which index of the matrix they are. Start by assuming ppl spread evenly along i dimension
value = zeros(n_year, n_ppl);
value(1,:) = randi([1 dim], [1,n_ppl]);

% initialize t1/t2
t1 = zeros(n_ppl, dim);
t2 = zeros(n_ppl, dim);

% METHOD 1: USING REPMAT
% with n_ppl = 1000, takes: 4.16 seconds
tic
% now simulate out the chain
for t = 2:n_year

 t1 = repmat(rand_numbers(t,:)', 1,dim);
 t2 = cum_transition(value(t-1,:),:);

 value(t,:) = 1+sum(t1>t2,2)';

end
toc

% METHOD 2: USING BSXFUN
% with n_ppl = 1000, takes: 7.3 seconds
tic
t1 = zeros(n_ppl, 1);
for t= 2:n_year

t1 = rand_numbers(t,:);
t2 = cum_transition(value(t-1,:),:);

value(t,:) = 1 + sum(bsxfun(@gt, t1,t2'));
end
toc
```

Comment: `1+sum(t1>t2,2)';` may produce unexpected result. Sometimes `sum(t1>t2,2)` generates a vector that contains `dim` and when you insert `1+dim` into `value` you can not use `value` to index `cum_transition` in the next iteration.

Comment: Did you try sticking that expression in a for loop over the elements of that column of `value`? For loops are actually pretty fast now in MATLAB, and complex indexing like this is one of the slowest things you can do. Extracting a single column at a time might be faster. You then don't need `repmat`, do the comparison per column, and save to `value` one element at a time.

Comment: Thanks -- I just tried indexing 1-by-1; it's about 1.5 times slower.

Comment: Thanks - yes, for the dimension -- I actually ran into this problem; it's safer to do size(cum_transition,1) - sum((t2>t1),2) + 1